# Purpose of star operator when used on List

Tags: python

What is the star operator doing to the input argument list in this example?

```
def main(name, data_dir='.'):
    print 'name', type(name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(*sys.argv)
```

Concretely, if I run the program with the star operator it prints:

```
name <type 'str'>
```

if run without the star `main(sys.argv)` it prints:

```
name <type 'list'>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `*` operator [unpacks an argument list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). It allows you to call a function with the list items as individual arguments.

For instance, if `sys.argv` is `["./foo", "bar", "quux"]`, `main(*sys.argv)` is equivalent to `main("./foo", "bar", "quux")`.

Answer (score 3):

```
main(*sys.argv)
```

calls `main` with the content of the list `sys.argv` as respective arguments of the `main` method and is in this case equivalent to:

```
main(sys.argv[0])
```

or

```
main(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1])
```

depending on the length of `sys.argv`.

So if you call it with the asterisk, it passes to `name` the first element of the list `sys.argv`.

If you call it without the asterisk, it passes to `name` the whole list `sys.argv`.

Comment: But @Frédéric Hamidi showed the entire list instead of first argument. Why not just main("./foo") instead of main("./foo", "bar", "quux")?