# Most "pythonic" way to check ordering of sub lists of a list?

Tags: python

what's the most "pythonic" way to calculate if a list of list has each element greater than its neigbbour? eg

```
a = [[3.1, 3.13], [3.14, 3.12], [3.12, 3.1]]
```

I want to see if the first element in each of the list (inside the bigger list) is greater than the 2nd element. So for first item, its false because 3.1 < 3.13. 2nd and 3rd item is true.

I can most certainly use a for loop, but would like to see alternative approaches. thanks.

Comment: do not overvalue "pythonic" way of doing things in python. To keep code clean is much more important. Evidently you can use "pythonic" map function with simple lambda for this task, but in this way your code won't be much clean. Keep the things simple for understanding, do not avoid for loops if it is natural to use them.

Comment: It is not natural to use stacked loop if you can use list comprehension which is a powerful and easily readable pythonic tool. In this particular case at least.

Comment: @AlexanderSmirnov Pythonic *is* clean and simple! Never mistake Pythonic to mean complex, because when you gain unnecessarily complex, because when you gain complexity, you lose Pythonicity.

Comment: kqr, sashkello I agree with you. I like list comprehension solution for this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pattern matching and list comprehension:

```
[x > y for x, y in a]
```

Comment: Not that it really matters, but one can omit the brackets in the for loop part if one wanted.

Comment: SethMMorton, of course, I just wasn't sure if you could do that with lists. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This will return a list of boolean values:

```
[x[0] > x[1] for x in a]
```

If you want to return True if all values are True and False otherwise:

```
all([x[0] > x[1] for x in a])
```

Comment: Not that it really matters, but one can omit the brackets in the all version in one wants. (apologies to SetMMorton)

Comment: @Thomas Yeah, you can, I find it a bit harder to read though personally as it is not immediately subconsciously associated with a list, which it is.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from operator import ge
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> a = [[3.1, 3.13], [3.14, 3.12], [3.12, 3.1]]
>>> list(starmap(ge, a))
[False, True, True]
```

or if you don't want to import `starmap`

```
>>> map(ge, *zip(*a))
[False, True, True]
```

Comment: hi, the asterix is to "expand" the arguments?

Comment: That's a nice use of higher-order functions.

Comment: That's importing `operator` and `itertools` for a simple list comprehension. I am a astonished that `numpy` hasn't been imported.

Comment: @dorothy see answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077268/purpose-of-star-operator-when-used-on-list In this case, it creates a list of tuples and passes them through ge as two arguments each.